# exacttarget Automation studio : cannot schedule the Automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation

I tried to schedule automation for filter activity in Automation Studio but cannot and gives me the error::

"Automation Saved, With Problems. "AUTOMATION_TEST 20140429" saved but not scheduled. Specified schedule was invalid.

And i Define the Schedule as the following :

Start : 2014-04-30 at 6:00

time zone : set

Repeat : Daily every : 1 Day

End : never

--Any idea?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific account issue, and should directly contact help@exacttarget.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kelly was almost right here - it is actually the time that is the problem.

When selecting from the drop down list for the time (in my case at least), I have the choice of 0:00 - 23:30 (24hr format) and the text then displays as so when selected in the drop down.

The time however needs to be in 12 hour format e.g. '13:30' needs to be '1:30 PM' - so using the drop-down is pointless for us right now.

I have reported the bug to ET, but for the time being this is the solution that our marketers are having to use.

Comment: I didn't think to check the time - I stopped at the date. Thanks!

Comment: [@KellyJAndrews](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/4786/kelly-j-andrews) et. al. - Thanks for the help getting the post reopened so I could get my answer in.

Comment: yes, for the time being as said '12 hour format e.g. '13:30' needs to be '1:30 PM' solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

The start date should be `04/30/2014` not `2014-04-30`.

Comment: it picks itself when i choose date from start calender..The format seems based on Timezone here...

Comment: When I ran through it in my account, it displayed as above. It may be based on your location.  Try updating the date to the above format and see if that works.

Comment: I tried to change the Timezone and /or Date format ...But no success..

Comment: I would contact help support then - I'm not able to help you out on this forum for this particular issue. Sorry!